# Check if customer logged in not working

Tags: magento2, login, toplinks, customer-session, custom-block

I have a block to add link at top based on if customer login like this, when i'm at myaccount page the header link show the right one, but when i go to other page it shows the wrong one, here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{

protected function _toHtml()
    {
     if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
     return parent::_toHtml();
     }
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
     $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
     if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
       return '<li><a href="/test/loggedin" > Logged In </a></li>' ;
     } else {
       return '<li><a href="/test/notloggedin" > Not Logged In </a></li>';
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Comment: when full page cache enable it will not work like that way there is another way to check this please find it on google it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `cacheable="false"` your module with xml file like this,

```
<block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Link" name="customname" cacheable="false">
```

Remove var/generation and clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this block code in cms or block content

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/}}
```

it will show you **signin** or **signout**